# React Native Credit Card reader

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, react-native

We are working on a new feature in our react native app that will allow us to read our own magnetic stripe cards. I am aware that the card reader simply acts as an external keyboard but not sure how well that would fare with react native due to the absence of the DOM and fancy jQuery would be hard to implement.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how we could do this?

Thanks again!

Comment: I assume you've seen this already... https://github.com/BBB/react-native-card.io? It's iOS only, but maybe you can help them with android support or get some ideas from their implementation.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman thanks for the response. Ive looked at it but I am looking to read data from the magnetic stripe using a magnetic stripe reader.

Comment: You might check for a Cordova plugin, they work on Android https://github.com/axemclion/react-native-cordova-plugin. IOS would take more effort unfortunately